# I have to map $\Re(z),\Im(z)\in\{\pm 2,\pm 1,0\}$ (Those 10 lines) through $f(z):=\frac{1}{z-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, linear-transformations

I have to map $\Re(z),\Im(z)\in\{\pm 2,\pm 1,0\}$ (Those 10 lines) through $f(z):=\frac{1}{z-1}$, but unsure what an easy/quick way to do it is. The only way I really know how to is that if I have the line as a set $(S=\{z : |z-w_1| = |z-w_2|\})$, then I know what $f(S)$ is, but that then requir

In this instance, I know $f(S)=\{z : |z-f(w_1)| = \left|\frac{w_2-1}{w_1-1}\right|\cdot|z-f(w_2)|\}$ since the matrix associated to $f$ is $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1):

Parametrize your lines as $l(t) =c_1 t + \gamma$ for $t \in \mathbb R$ and $\gamma \in \mathbb C$. Further suppose $c_1 = a + bi$ and $\gamma = c + di$

Then,
$$1/(c_1t+\gamma-1) = 1/((a + bi) + c+di - 1)$$
$$=\frac{at+c-1}{a^2t^2+2c(at-1)-2at+b^2t^2+2bdt+c^2+d^2+1} - \frac{bt+d}{(at+c-1)^2 + (bt+d)^2} i$$

If you plug in $c=0, d=0$,

$$=\frac{at-ibt-1}{(at-1)^2+b^2t^2}$$

Now simply plugging in your choices of $a,b$, for example, $2i$ case corresponds with $a=0$, $b=2$:

$$=\frac{-2it-1}{1+4t^2}=\frac{i}{2t-i}$$

Comment: Bro you are absolutely wrong

Comment: hat's the point of introducing gamma if you just then make it 0?

Comment: And in the example you gave, how do you go about recognizing $i/(2t-i)$ as either a line or circle?

Comment: and how do you parameterize a vertical line in C as the question says?

Comment: A parameterization of any line passing through points $z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb C$ is $z_1t + z_2(1-t)$. So by vertical line, you mean passing through which points of the complex plane? And the gamma is there if you want to generalize to arbitrary lines instead of lines specifically through the origin.

Comment: Also, $i/(2t-i)$ is neither a line nor circle. It is the image of a line under the transformation $z \mapsto 1/(z-1)$. Are you looking for calculating preimages of $1/(z-1)$ instead as your question? i.e. which inputs give us the lines you specified? Because if that is what you are looking for I can write that instead, I may have misinterpreted image instead of preimage. It would have helped if you had been a bit more specific about it though it's no problem I can write the other one depending on what you are still looking for.

Comment: For example, the function $ z \mapsto (t-i)/t$ sends $1/(z-1)$ to $it$. You can find those by setting them equal and doing standard algebraic operations

Comment: Ah or maybe you meant lines in $\mathbb C^2$ actually, not lines in $\mathbb C$? Or lines in $\mathbb C \times \mathbb R$ perhaps? My answer is assuming a line in the complex plane as a map $\Gamma : \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ whose images are in bijection with the (images of the) parameterizations $t \mapsto c_1t + \gamma$. Let me know where our thought processes are diverging and I'll fix up the answer to tailor to those specifics.